# bash script prova.sh: line 76: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: bash, eof, unexpectendoffile

I have below script but I can't find the error. Somebody an help me ?

In concrete I split a big file in different then compress any file, move it and send by ftp rename destination filename.

Something not work :(

in line:
put ${file} ${7}.T${j}(+1)

I try to rename the file with (+1) ended new filename

Kind regards

```
#!/bin/bash

# configuration stuff

# ${1} absolute path file
# ${2} num_files
# ${3} output_filename
# ${4} ipMainframe ip to put files
# ${5} FTP username
# ${6} FTP password
# ${7} destination filename

if [ ! $# == 7 ]; then
        #number of parameter different of two
        echo "Number of parameter incorrect"
        echo "Command use: LLP_split_gzip_sendFTPandTrigger.sh absolute_path_file number_of_pieces output_filename ipMainframe userFTP pwdFTP destinationFilename"
        exit 1
fi

if [ -f ${1} ]; then
        # If file exists
        if [[ ${2} =~ ^[\-0-9]+$ ]] && (( ${2} > 0)); then
                # if number of pieces is an integer > 0
                #Remove old files
                echo "home directory = $HOME"
                CMD=`rm -f '"$HOME"/"$3"*'`
                if [ $? != 0 ]; then
                        echo "Impossible to remove old files $home/llp_tmp* $home/"$3"* in home directory"
                        echo $CMD
                fi
                # Calculate line for every file splitted
                total_lines=$(cat ${1} | wc -l)
                ((lines_per_file = (total_lines + ${2} - 1) / ${2}))
                # Split the actual file, maintaining lines.
                CMD=`split -l "$lines_per_file" "$1" "$HOME"/llp_tmp`
                if [ $? != 0 ]; then
                        echo "SPLITTING FILE ERROR: problem to split file."
                        echo $CMD
                        exit 3
                fi
                #For every file splitted rename and zip it
                i=1
                for file in $HOME/llp_tmp*; do
                        CMD=`mv "$file" "$3"."$i"`
                        if [ $? != 0 ]; then
                                echo "Impossible to rename file"
                                echo $CMD
                                exit 5
                        fi
                        CMD=`gzip "$3"."$i"`
                        if [ $? != 0 ]; then
                                echo "Impossible to compress file $3.$i"
                                echo $CMD
                                exit 6
                        fi
                        i=`expr $i + 1`
                done
                ftp -n ${4} << EOF

                j=1
                user ${5} ${6}
                for file in $3.*; do
                        put ${file} ${7}.T${j}(+1)
                        j=`expr $j + 1`
                done
                quit
        else
                echo "number of pieces second parameter must be more than 0."
                exit 2
        fi
else
        echo "absolute path first paramater doesnt exist"
        exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not terminating your here document.  When I run your script I get:

```
gash.sh: line 72: warning: here-document at line 54 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
gash.sh: line 73: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

`ftp -n ${4} << EOF` is the issue.  Where is your here document?

The warning says it all, you don't have an `EOF` marker.  Note that this MUST NOT BE INDENTED!  The `EOF` must be in "column 0" and have no trailing characters, including whitespace.

Edit:  It appears you want to use program constructs within a single FTP session - I don't know of a way of doing that in Bash.  Perl has an easy to use FTP module where you can do it, simple example:

```
use strict;
use Net::FTP;

my $ftp = Net::FTP->new ("hostname");
$ftp->login ("username", "password");
$ftp->binary ();

for my $file (glob("$ENV{HOME}/llp_tmp*")) {

    $ftp->put ($file); 
}
$ftp->quit();
```

Comment: but If I substitute this line with:

CMD=`ftp -n "$4" << EOF`

give me the same error.

My problem is open FTP session in not interactive mode and put files renaming them by a loop but I need to add an EOF when I call FTP -n command for not interactive mode.

Do you know How I can solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need parentheses around `+1`.

Change it to:

```
put "${file}" "${7}.T${j}+1"
```

It's good practice to quote variables.

Another tip: Instead of `` j=`expr $j + 1` ``, you can simply use `((j++))`.